# Class attribute which is not present on subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Mostly for fun, to help with some ergonomics in a parser that I'm writing, I would like very much to override a class' `__getattr__` without doing the same for its subclasses. To explain, some code:

```py
class AttrMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "A":
            return "hi there."

class Main(metaclass=AttrMeta):
    pass

class Subclass(Main):
    pass

print(Main.A)  # => hi there.
print(Subclass.A) # => hi there.
print(Main().A) # => AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'A'
print(Subclass().A) # => AttributeError: 'Subclass' object has no attribute 'A'
```

This is all normal, but what I would like is for `Subclass` not to inherit the `__getattr__`. To do this, the first thing I tried was overriding `__new__` in `AttrMeta` as follows:

```py
# in AttrMeta...
def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
    if bases:
        return type.__new__(type, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs) 
    return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
```

The idea here was to strip the metaclass off of subclasses of `Main`, which are detected by looking at the `bases`. This led to some infinite recursions when creating the `class Subclass(Main)`, which makes sense -- how could you have such a broken inheritance chain?

My next idea was to delete the `__getattr__` by hand:

```py
# in AttrMeta...
def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
    new_cls = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
    if bases:
        del new_cls.__getattr__
    return new_cls
```

Well, what's obvious in retrospect is you can't do that: you get an `AttributeError: __getattr__`. That's because `Subclass.__getattr__` is bound to `AttrMeta` -- in fact, `"__getattr__" not in dir(Subclass)` holds.

At this point, I said to myself, hey. Tim Peters said that people who need metaclasses know that for a fact, and I am simply not one of those people. In fact I don't really "need" to be writing this parser at all, I'm just trying to, you know, get a little diversion during quarantine. Perhaps I shall just do this by assigning to `__getattr__` on the class and see what happens. So, I tried:

```py
class Main:
    pass

class Subclass(Main):
    pass

def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == "A":
        return "hi there."

Main.__getattr__ = __getattr__

Main.A # raises AttributeError: type object 'Main' has no attribute 'A'
```

At this point I've run out of ideas. I'll probably just give up and allow `Subclass` to have the attribute getter. I don't want to override `__getattr__` on every single `Subclass` since there are many, but I was curious if there are any ideas out there. Thanks for reading this long post.

Comment: Setting `Main.__getattr__` isn't supposed to work (that applies to instances of `Main`, not `Main` itself), but the errors should have been much more normal AttributeErrors, not what you report. Those must have come from some other weird thing interfering with attribute access, maybe IPython or an IDE or something.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I was running these in IPython. Edited to remove the stuff relating to those errors.

Comment: While you can do this, it violates the [substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_subtyping) of base- and child-classes. In other words, you are breaking inherent assumptions that are likely to be made for your classes. Are you absolutely sure this is not some Y of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: I'm sure it is haha. Doubtless my whole parser project is ys and xs all the way down... anyway figured out an answer which makes a sort of inheritance diamond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured out at least one way that works. The idea is to add a new metaclass like so:

```py
class AttrMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        if bases:
            mcs = NoMoreMeta
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "A":
            return "hi there."


class NoMoreMeta(AttrMeta):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "A":
            raise AttributeError(name)


class Main(metaclass=AttrMeta):
    pass


class Subclass(Main):
    pass
```

Then `Main.A` works as above but `Subclass.A` raises the appropriate error.

Answer (score 0):

One can't make an attribute or method to be "not inherited" in Python - you  can just shadow a previously existing method or attribute on subclasses, and you can use that to inject a replacement that will raise an AttributeError.

In this case, since Python 3.6, you don't even need a metaclass - you can use the `__init_subclass__` method, that is run when a subclass is created (but not the current class), to replace the `__getattr__` with one that will raise:

```py
class Main:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == "A":
            return "A"
        raise AttributeError()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            # blocks the original getattr
            raise AttributeError(attr)

        # optional check: allow subclasses to implement their own __getattr__ methods:
        if "__getattr__" in cls.__dict__:
            return
        cls.__getattr__ = __getattr__


class SubClass(Main):
    pass
```

And this runs:

```py
In [95]: Main().A                                                                                              
Out[95]: 'A'

In [96]: SubClass().A                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError
```

However, you are adding `__getattr__` to the metaclass themselves - 
(shame on me, I just saw it now) - so the dynamic atttributes can
be seem on the classes, not just on intances.

The easier way to go them is to mark the original "Base" class with some
attribute, and on the metaclass `__getattr__` check if the getattr is being
called on that base class.

(The `__init_subclass__` approach won't work, as the metaclass itself
is the same, there is no "subclass of the metaclass"  to be used
by the Main class subclasses)

```py
mark = "_AttrBase"

def find_marked(cls):
    for sclass in cls.__mro__:
        if sclass.__dict__.get(mark, False):
            return sclass
    return None

class AttrMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwd):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwd)
        if not find_marked(cls):
            # This line injects a getattr on the instances as well, so 
            # that instances have the same behavior for these as the classes:
            cls.__getattr__ = lambda self, attr: getattr(self.__class__, attr)
            setattr(cls, mark, True)
        return cls

    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        if find_marked(cls) is not cls:
            raise AttributeError(attr)
        if attr == "A":
            return "A"
        raise AttributeError(attr)

class Main(metaclass=AttrMeta):
    pass

class SubClass(Main):
    pass
```